# Python Wedding Seating plan

Tags: python

I am getting married in three months and what to attempt create a python code that will pick my seating plan for me as a project to improve my coding further. On the day there will be 10 tables for 100 guests. I want to build a sample to see how effective it is but struggling with ideas on how best to do it as I am fairly new to python coding.

I decided to start with a matrix which determines how much each guest knows each other. The more positive the number the better, the more negative the number the more they dislike each other.

Below is an example: 12 guests try would like to try and get 3 tables. Any suggestions on how to optimize this or a better way to go about it would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Sample]

Comment: Sorry, this is not something we can help you with here at Stack Overflow. We can help with more focused practical programming problems, a general 'how do I solve this bigger problem' is too broad.

Comment: Any recommendations on where I could ask a broad question like this?

Comment: This is a hard problem. With 12 people and 3 tables you could do a brute-force search, but that would take (almost) forever on your real problem. You may be able to get help on our sister site Software Engineering, but please read their Help tour first so you know how to make an on-topic question.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Perhaps a genetic programming approach would work, maximizing for 'happiness' calculated across the seating plan generated. Not something to give to a beginner programmer, though.